# Obtaining a user input value with pygame_textinput module?

Tags: python, pygame, textinput

I've been working in my spare time on a simple game using pygame to allow me to get familiar with its code. The game I am making is a abstraction of a Four in a Row game which implements maths questions. To get the user's answer I am using a module called pygame_textinput. However, I am struggling to extract the user's answer which I want to then be able to compare to the correct answer, which will allow the user to place their disk in the grid.

The code for this I have is:

```
mathsanswer = pygame_textinput.TextInput()
```

This is outside of the main loop which I then call upon in the code below.

```
mathsanswer.update(events) #Check if user has inputted text
display.blit(mathsanswer.get_surface(), (600,725))
```

This part of the code works perfectly as the text the user types is displayed on screen.

However when I try to extract what the user has typed I get:

```
<pygame_textinput.TextInput object at 0x00000219C1F101D0>
```

Is there a way to get what the user has typed as the variable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the code that you use to try to get the input as a variable?

Comment: @johnashu I haven't got any code to try to get it as a variable. All i've tried to do is print (mathsanswer) which is when I get that value. I'm not sure how I would turn that into the what the user has typed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. you need to use `get_text()` to get the input.

To catch the user input after the user hits Return, simply evaluate the return value of the update()-method - it is always False except for when the user hits Return, then it's True. To get the inputted text, use get_text(). Example:

```
if mathsanswer.update(events):
    print(mathsanswer.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: can you select it as the correct answer please? the green tick :)  Good luck with the game !